# what does blanket merge mean with respect to source code management systems?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, perforce

Let us say there are branches 1 and 2. Does blanket merge from 2 to 1 means, replacing contents of 1 with contents of 2 blindly?

Comment: Where did you find the term `blanket merge`? It's not one with which I'm familiar, and the only relevant hit I'm seeing on Google is this question.

Comment: Me too. Just used in one of our company's internal meetings and I have no way to reach the person who used it directly.

Comment: Me too; perhaps he means copy merge i.e. --theirs

Answer (score 2):

The only references that I'm seeing to a "blanket merge" seem to be pointing to [subversion issue 4387](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4387). That states that `svn merge --record-only` can be used to prevent changes from being included in a blanket merge.

This makes it sounds like (at least to that person) this would be referring to a blanket merge as what is the only type of merge within git, where the full history of a commit is merged into the current branch. So a non-blanket merge in git would be a cherry-pick.

But, since there only seems to be the one use of the term, I'd say that it doesn't seem to be in common use. So if the use is in question you'll need to get clarification from the person who used it.